# Php Select few rows

Tags: php

I have written simple php script to select my Blog data.
On this moment I have like a 20 blogs on my site. and it looks not nice anymore.
I would like to put about 5 blogs on 1 site and the rest on index.php?id=2,3,4,5 and like that. I'm looking for some tutorial how to do it.

```html
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogData ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$title = $row['title'];
$content = $row['content'];
$date = $row['date'];

?>
     
  <?php
}
?>
```

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to pass starting pages with GET array - as you have written.

1. Set defaults:

   ```
   $pageNumber=0;
   $postsPerPage=5;
   ```
2. Get current pageNumber:

   ```
   $pageNumber=$isset($_GET['pn'])?:$pageNumber;

   //try to secure this value i.e:
   if(!is_numeric($pageNumber)) exit('Value not allowed');
   ```
3. Make SQL statement

   ```
   $startRow=$pageNumber*$postsPerPage;

   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogData ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$startRow.",'.$postsPerPage);

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
       $title = $row['title'];
       $content = $row['content'];
       $date = $row['date'];

       //show your blog post as you want

   }
   ```
4. Generate pager:

   ```
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total FROM blogData);
   $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
   $countBlogPosts=$data['total'];

       for($i=0;$<$countBlogPosts;$i++){
           if($i==$pageNumber){
                echo $i+1;
           }else{
                echo '<a href="/?pn='.$i.'" > '.($i+1).' </a>';
           }
           if($i<$countBlogPosts-1) echo "|";
       }
   ```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you very freaking much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show only 5 row of your table, use :

```
$start = $_GET['id'] * 5;
$limit = 5;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogData ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start,$limit");
```

and you can get the page number and use in query. (start from row $start and show the top 5).

for making pagination , you should first get the count of all row in table. then div it to 5.
(e.g the number rows in table is 141, and 141/5=28. so you have 28 page.)

you should combine the PHP code and HTML for make pagination.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called [pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination).

It is simple as making a change in your query for example:

```
SELECT * FROM blogData ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :start, :end
```

So you just need to manage to pass the right values in your query strings.

It should be that simple, but [there are tons of tutorial on pagination](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20pagination%20mysql).